# How to trigger screenshot on every validator/Assert pass and fail using testng listener

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I want to take screenshot for every validator/assert pass and fail steps. Let me know if we have testng listeners can help me to implement this scenario as I am new to selenium webdriver and testng automation testing

Answer (score 0):

You can take screen-shot by following :

```
        File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);      
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
        File filetest = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\Screenshots\\"+ "ScreenshotName" + ".png"));
```

Here, Screenshot will save in "Screenshots" folder(Which you need to create) under project workspace by using Absolute path. If you want to save on other location, You can locate path for same.

If you want TestNG validator on every @Test whether its pass or fail, you can implement it in AfterMethod.

```
@AfterMethod
public void testStatus(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        testResult = "Test Fail :" + result.getName();
        testResult = "Details of Fail Testcase:" + result.getThrowable();
        }
}
```

You can define above Screenshot utility in testStatus method, which will take screen shot if @Test got fail.

Comment: how to get screenshot at every step or for every method, problem is  many test cases which has 300+ methods I don't want to call takeScreenshot() method in every method that would be headache, any better way to do it like using `@aspect` annotation or something like that .. any pointers on this would be really appreciated

Comment: Yóu can create singe function, and after you just have to call ít by single liné.